# `tramp-verbose` setting has no effect on `*debug tramp*` buffer

Tags: tramp, performance

Emacs 29.1, Tramp 2.6.0.29.1

I believe the log messages in the `*debug tramp*` buffer are slowing down TRAMP. With the `tramp-verbose` set to the default value of 1, my `*debug tramp*` buffer accumulated about 5 million lines. (Many of these lines are about `auto-revert` and Magit, both used through TRAMP.)

I have set `tramp-verbose` to 0, cleared all buffers, restarted Emacs, and begun a new TRAMP session. It seems to be faster. The `*debug tramp*` started with 0 lines. However, it is growing again. Is there a way to control this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with your settings. The Tramp debug buffer is touched only when `tramp-verbose` is at least 4. Call

```
# emacs -Q -l tramp --eval '(setq tramp-verbose 3)'
```

Do some remote editing. There won't be a Tramp debug buffer.